# Android SDK Tools 21: Help in Compile with tab

Tags: android, android-sdk-tools, android-4.2-jelly-bean

[image]

Recently I updated SDK, and this new 'compile with' option appears.. what does it mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means that despite targetSdk, "compile with SDK" version will be used. This is helpful to target higher SDK and avoid accidental use of newer API. Or, in other words, you want to target API17 but stay compatible with API8 without much effort. So you set target to API17 but compile with to API8. Now, if you code for any reason use anything that was introduced in API9 or up it will not compile. Previously app was build with API version set as target sdk

**EDIT**

After closer look I think this is broken. It is basically not saved neither in project.properties nor elsewhere, therefore it does not really serve described purpose, outside "New Project Wizard", which will generate code/layout stubs to match "compile with" API version.

Filled bug report: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=40286

Comment: You can use ADT v21. But be aware that stuill it's **you** who has to pay attention and to not use higher API if set minSdk and targetSdk to different values as (currently) tools won't do that, despite misleading setting in wizard.

Answer (score 0):

Compile With is the platform version against which you will compile your app. By default, this is set to the latest version of Android available in your SDK. (It should be Android 4.1 or greater; if you don't have such a version available, you must install one using the SDK Manager). You can still build your app to support older versions, but setting the build target to the latest version allows you to enable new features and optimize your app for a great user experience on the latest devices.
[source](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/creating-project.html)